# Not getting DTMF digits during call

Tags: asterisk, digit, dtmf

I am writing a simple asterisk extension plan, In which when user calls, User press key and that key store to a text file.

For this i write this extension:-

```
exten => 203,1,Answer()
exten => 203,2,Read(NUMBER1||1)
exten => 203,3,System(echo 'User entered ${NUMBER1}' >> /tmp/key.txt)
exten => 203,4,Hangup()
```

But whenever i call and press any key, file only have 'User entered', Means i am not getting key.
What i am doing wrong here?

Here is my sip.conf for extension:-

```
[mysjphone]
type=friend
host=dynamic
username=mysjphone
secret=blablabla
allow=gsm
dtmfmode = rfc2833
host = dynamic
```

Note: I am doing this in windows server (astriskwin32).

Answer (score 0):

That package is built on an extremely old version of Asterisk, 1.2.x.  Since that time, there were many, many improvements made to Asterisk's ability to detect and process RFC2833 DTMF events.  You'll likely want to upgrade to a much newer version of Asterisk.  For more information about Asterisk versions, please see:

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Versions